# Typing Chinese in /title Tag

Tags: fonts, titles, languages, cjk

I am currently writing a document thesis document in English, however I need to add the translation of the thesis title in Chinese as well.

I wanted to add it in the \title tag, just like this:

```
\title { [English Text here] \\
[Chinese Text here]
}
```

However it is not working. I am currently using \usepackage{CJKutf8} along with \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi} environment.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using hyperref? Don't know if it has problems with chinese letters, but it has with other special characters